# Ms Access : Query to work out percentage

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a database which currently records the amount of times someone does a certain procedure and they scores they have received. The scoring is done by select a value of either N, B or C.

I currently have written a query which will count the total number of times a procedure is done and the amount of times each score is received.

Here is the result of the query (original: http://www.flickr.com/photos/mattcripps/6673555339/)

[image: Query Results]

and here is the code

```
    TRANSFORM Count(ed.[Entry ID]) AS [CountOfEntry ID]
SELECT ap.AdultProcedureName, ap.Target, Count(ed.[Entry ID]) AS [Total Of Entry ID]
FROM tblAdultProcedures AS ap LEFT JOIN tblEntryData AS ed ON ap.AdultProcedureName = ed.[Adult Procedure]
GROUP BY ap.AdultProcedureName, ap.Target
PIVOT ed.Grade;
```

If a score of N or B is given that is deemed below standard and C is deemed at standard. Is there a way I can add something to my query which will show me in percentage how many of the procedures we at standard and how many below?

I really cant get my head round this so any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not exactly, but you can get a crosstab query that consists of one line and you can use that query as the basis of another query, however, I suggest that you go about this in a more conventional way and use a report to present the percentages.

Comment: @Remou how could I go about doing that in a report?

Comment: @user1132612 You would write a normal cross-tab query like the existing one, and then you wrap this inside a select query so it uses the cross-tab query as a table in the select query.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TabProd
SET PrecProd = (PrecProd * 1.1)
WHERE Código IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar to this on a pretty large scale.

My issue was the need to be able to run queries over specific (but user variable) timeframes and output similar percentage of total results in a report.

I won't get into the date issue but my solution was to run the "sum" function on the total line on my specific reject criteria to get totals of the rejects then use a divide expression to create a new column element (defined expression) in the same query pulling from the joined table of "Total net production" - joined by a common reference - job ID.

For your case it sounds like you want to sum the two failure types - which you would simply add defined expressions dividing your total instances into your various failure modes and formatting in your output report as percents. To finish the data portion of your report you then need a third expression defining your "non-fail percent" - which would be 1.0 - N/total - B/total - both of which you will have previously defined in the query to determine the N and B failure rates.

Then its a matter of pulling that information into your report and formatting. It definitely CAN be done.

Hope this helps.